# Scroll View-Pager and Recycler-View android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I'm creating a new layout that has view pager with recycler view and I want both scrollable at the same moment. Whether I set scroll view to scroll both, suggest me, this is my code suggest me what can I add for my goal.

Like the amazon slider:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight=".8"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#BEBEBE"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/db_btns"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/db_btns"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/slider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/db_btns"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

[image: Sample Picture]

Comment: just try add `nestedscroll = false` on Recyclerview and see